# Server is down, is there an alternative server for ECF than ecftcp://ecf.eclipse.org:3282/

Tags: eclipse, pair-programming, eclipse-ecf

I was trying to setup up the [Eclipse CollaborationFramework](http://127.0.0.1:3322/help/topic/org.eclipse.ecf.doc/html/gettingstarted/quickStart.html) using the [doc share plgin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/DocShare_Plugin)

I managed to connect the through google talk OK, but when I tried to create a collboration to share the workspace, on trying to connect to ther server I got a connection failed error, could not connect to the server

Anybody know if

1. is the server not available anymore?
2. is there an alternative elsewhere?
3. Would i be better creating my own?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create an ECF server - there's a FAQ on how to launch the server at wiki.eclipse.org.

From the command line, you can invoke it as an Eclipse application:

```
eclipse.exe -console -application org.eclipse.ecf.provider.AppGenericServer 1234
```

That starts a port on ecftpc://localhost:1234

You can also bring up an OSGi command line and use startApp to ring up an instance. This will allow you to have multiple servers in the same runtime.

```
java -Declipse.application.registerDescriptors=true -Declipse.ignoreApp=false -jar org.eclipse.osgi -console -noExit 
osgi> startApp org.eclipse.ecf.provider.GenericServer 1234
osgi> startApp org.eclipse.ecf.provider.GenericServer 5678
```

Sorry I couldn't point you to the [FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/ECF_Servers#Starting_an_ECF_Generic_Server_as_Eclipse_Application) directly before.

Comment: Are you referring to this page? http://wiki.eclipse.org/ECF_Servers#Setting_up_an_ECF_Generic_Server_with_Equinox

Comment: That's the page, but this is the easiest way:

eclipse.exe -console -application org.eclipse.ecf.provider.AppGenericServer

You can also start it from the Equinox OSGi console using 
osgi> startApp org.eclipse.ecf.provider.GenericServer 3333